# Creating heat map with fixed max color value in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, heat-map, mapping

I am trying to create a heat map using raster data in QGIS 3.0. I have made them previously in ArcGIS pretty easily, but I am having difficulties in QGIS. The difficulty I am having is setting a fixed max color value (in this case, it's $400M). The procedure I take is as follows:

1. Load the raster set into QGIS
2. Convert to a heat map via Symbology (no changes made to default options)
3. Open Processing Toolbox, Interpolation, Heatmap (Kernel Density Estimation)
4. Save as .tif file.
5. Load in .tif file, go to Style
6. Change max value to the value I am interested in ($400M).

In the end, I just get a big circle looking like this. [image]

In a nutshell, I want something like this (the max value is about 200M)  [image]

But instead, the best I can do is this, before I export out the heatmap as a .tif (after step 2) (where 200M is the max color, instead of 400M) [image]

Any ideas here?

Comment: Have you tried the heat map layer renderer? If you filter your features to the $400m max, you can render a heatmap on just those points and now worry about creating a 'density' layer, which the Heatmap 'geoprocessing' tool is trying to create...

Comment: Looks like your radius parameter value is much too high from the screenshots

Comment: Where is the renderer you're talking about? I see some references to rendering but not 100% sure what you mean.